# Centos repo Change from 6.4 to 6

Tags: centos, yum

Centos 6.4 receives no updates 
I have a centos VM and i have to install perl

The mirror no longer exists 
how to change the Centos version link in the yum Repo 
from 6.4 to 6

```
 http://mirrors.vonline.vn/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/dbus-glib-0.86-6.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"


Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
http://centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/perl-5.10.1-131.el6_4.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
Trying other mirror.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install Perl directly like this;
For a 64-bit processor:

```
rpm -Uhv http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

For a 32-bit processor:

```
rpm -Uhv http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/perl-5.10.1-136.el6.i686.rpm
```

After that you could have a look at the URL's in your repository;
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo